# box shadow applied to select option on Safari

Tags: css, safari

I am trying to launch my very first site, but there is always something...
Now safari is not rendering box-shadow inset "correctly". 
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gloak/8J89Q/). 
IE 10, Chrome and Firefox apply the shadow to the select box. Safari doesn't. Do you have any trick?

Please see good [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gloak/8J89Q/). Nothing to change there....

```
<input ...>
<select..>
</select>
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
```

CSS

Thank you so much!

Comment: Mate, Look at this answser on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890399/safari-box-shadow-inset-support

Comment: Thank you. I had seen that question form 2010. Just trying to find answer for 2013, if any different... Even explorer (against that old question) is rendering properly. Thank you anyway.